# Retrieving images in Android gallery through Intent

Tags: android, image, android-intent, gallery, galleryview

I am building a custom gallery in my app by populating it from Android gallery through intent. This is working fine but now I want to filter images.

For example I do not want all the images from the Android gallery but only images that were taken on a specific date. Can I set some filter or pack some extra parameters with my intent to Andriod gallery so that a subset of images that are required are returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You'll have to query this.**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html

**The columns you can select from being here.**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html

**Here is a blog post with solid code samples.**

http://androidsamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-display-thumbnails-of-images.html